# Uso de htonl en el payload de un paquete UDP

Tags: c++, windows, redes

Estoy enviado con winsock2 paquetes UDP de los cuales los 4 primeros bytes de la carga util son utilizados para identificar el paquete.

**Ejemplo basico:**

```
uint32_t id= 1 //Esta valor ira incrementando
uint8_t* buffer =new uint8_t[1400];
((uint32_t*)buffer )[0] = id; //guardamos en los primeros 4 bytes el id del paquete
...
//añadimos el resto de datos  a buffer
//Enviamos el paquete por red
```

La duda que me tengo:

¿Es necesario utilizar htonl para convertir el identificador antes de enviarlo?

¿Al resto de datos (bytes) debería aplicar esta transformación también?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿ Es necesario utilizar htonl para convertir el identificador antes de enviarlo ?
> ¿ Al resto de datos (bytes) debería aplicar esta transformación también ?

**Depende**.

La carga útil es responsabilidad **exclusivamente tuya**. Si estás **absoluta y completamente seguro** de que la máquina receptora usa el mismo *endian* y tienes bien definidos (en ambas partes) el tamaño de los datos a leer, **no** es necesario.

Entiende que esa información forma parte de la *capa de aplicación* OSI. El como la interpretes es responsabilidad exclusiva de tu código.

Tienes disponibles muchos formatos de intercambio de datos que ya tienen en cuenta esas cosas: Y a *unas malas*, puedes incluso transmitir tu información como *texto plano*, con lo que evitas posibles malinterpretaciones por temas de tamaño/*endian*.

Answer (score 3):

Hablando del ID del tipo de paquete:

Si es necesario o no, depende (como veremos más adelante).

Pero más allá de que sea necesario, SI que es deseable, pues es la convención seguir la convención puede evitarte dolores de cabeza. Vamos al meollo del asunto:

¿De qué depende?, ¿cómo determinar si es necesario?

- ¿Estás implementando un protocolo propio o alguno estándar o de un tercero?

  - Si es un protocolo estándar o de un tercero, lo más probable es que debas enviar todos los enteros en *network byte order*, pero no puedes asumirlo. **Lee la documentación** del protocolo o consulta con el soporte técnico o la comunidad de ese protocolo.
  - Si es un protocolo propio, mi sugerencia es que lo utilices. Eso te dará independencia de la plataforma. Puede ser que hoy tu única implementación esté sobre Windows/x86, pero mañana puedes estar corriendo clientes y/o servidores en Linux/x86, Linux/ARM, Android/ARM, Raspberry/ARM, Windows/ARM, iOS/ARM, MacOS/x86, MacOS/ARM y quien sabe qué otros dispositivos. Utilizar la convención te evitará dolores de cabeza.

Sobre el resto del contenido, no hay manera de responder sin saber de que se trata.

Si son números, sigue la recomendación.

Si no son números, diría que no hace falta, pero eres tú el responsable de determinarlo. Si de alguna manera se ve afectada la representación de los datos en otras plataformas distintas de tu plataforma actual, sigue alguna convención existente para estandarizar su representación mientras va *en el cable*, y en cada implementación la transformas a la representación válida para tu plataforma, que es exactamente lo que hace `htonl`, `ntohl` y demás funciones `hton?`/`ntoh?`.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Es necesario utilizar htonl para convertir el identificador antes de enviarlo?

La utilidad de htonl es convertir números a un formato independiente de la máquina utilizada.

Por ilustrar el caso clásico, imagina que tienes un servidor y un cliente, uno es big endian y el otro de tipo little endian. Si envias los números tal cual, el cliente recibirá un número diferente al enviado por el servidor:

```
servidor    cliente
00001111 -> 1111000
```

y esto hará que la comunicación entre ambos sea, cuanto menos, complicada.

Ahora bien, ¿es necesario? pues depende.

El único requisito para que una comunicación entre equipos funcione es que ambas máquinas deben utilizar el mismo protocolo, esto es, un conjunto de reglas que posibilitan la comunicación.

Así, puede suceder que el protocolo dicte que los números deben ir codificados con htonl, en complemento a 2, en bcd empaquetado o vete tu a saber... si tienes libertad para diseñar el protocolo y existe la posibilidad de que en la comunicación intervengan máquinas de diferente arquitectura, tendrás que atender a estos detalles para que la comunicación sea efectiva.

Si, en cambio, te ves obligado a usar un protocolo determinado, será el propio protocolo el que te indique cómo debes codificar ese número.

Si lo piensas un poco, verás que en las comunicaciones de tu día a día sucede exactamente lo mismo... si el lenguaje empleado (el protocolo) es diferente, la comunicación será más o menos complicada (si ambos lenguajes se parecen) o directamente imposible (si son lenguajes sin nada en común)

> ¿Al resto de datos (bytes) debería aplicar esta transformación también?

Nuevamente, depende de lo que dicte el protocolo que vayas a utilizar:

- Si tu diseñas el protocolo y las máquinas involucradas emplean la misma arquitectura... no es necesario pero si aconsejable
- En cualquier otro caso... sí, tendrás que codificar el resto de campos de alguna manera

Este problema no es nuevo y ya ha habido mucha gente ideando maneras de capear este problema. Así, tienes a tu disposición diferentes protocolos perfectamente funcionales:

- [XDR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1435/rpcgenpguide-21470/index.html)
- [ASN.1](https://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-made-simple/introduction.html)
- [ProtocolBuffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/tutorials)
- [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)
- ...